# VSCode Running a Script Using Macros

Tags: visual-studio-code

**tl;dr:**
I wanna run a script through a macro using "macros" extension for VSCode, see the extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros)
Is it possible? if yes, then how?
**long story:**
There is this extension called "powertools" (see it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ego-digital.vscode-powertools#commands-)), and I used it to add a custom button that runs a script when I click it.
I wanna add a functionality to this button, such that each time I click the button, it saves all of my files using this command ID `"workbench.action.files.saveAll"`, and then shall it run the script.

defining the button goes like this:

```
"ego.power-tools": {  
        "buttons": 
        [
            {
                "text": "Compile Folder",
                "tooltip": "Compile all the .Jack files in the current folder.",
                "action":
                {
                    "type": "command",
                    "command": "macros.compile_button_click",
                }
            }
        ],
    }
```

And I want the macro to look something like this:

```
"macros": {
        "compile_button_click": [
            "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
            {
                "action":
                    {
                        "type": "script",
                        "script": "compile_folder.js"
                    }
            },
          ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**P.S - It is important that the macro will first save the files, and only then shall it execute the script**

Comment: with `powertools` you can define a command to execute the `compile_folder.js`, add this command to your macro sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**THE SOLUTION:**
as @rioV8 said, using `powertools` you can define a command to execute a script, and then you can add the newly defined command to the `macros`.

**THIS IS HOW I DID IT:**

```
"ego.power-tools": {
        "buttons": 
        [
            {
                "text": "Save & Compile",
                "tooltip": "Compile all the .Jack files in the current folder.",

                // Running the macro on button click
                "action":
                    {
                        "type": "command",
                        "command": "macros.compile_button_click"
                    }
            }
        ],

        "commands": {

            // Define a command that runs a script
            "compile_folder": {
                "script": "compile_folder.js"
            }
        }
    },

    "macros": {

        // Define a macro command
        "compile_button_click": [
            "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
            "compile_folder"
          ]
    }
```